# How to use functions in open-source javascript file

Tags: javascript, function

I am using an open-source javascript file. there is a function among codes which I want to use it in my own codes. The structure of my file is like this:

```
function ($) {
    // there is codes here
    function _disable(input, v) { // I need this function 
        _o(input).prop('disabled', v);
        input.prop('disabled', v);
        var input_div = _getInputpickerDiv(input);
        if (v) {
            input_div.find('.inputpicker-arrow').hide();
        }
        else {
            input_div.find('.inputpicker-arrow').show();
        }
    }
    // there is codes here
});
```

I made a reference to the open-source file and tried below code:

```
<script src="assets/jquery.inputpicker.js"></script>

$("input").each(function () {
    _disable($(this), false);
});
```

But I am getting this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: _disable is not defined

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: That function is meant to be private, so you shouldn't be able to access it from the outside. You can only do so by modifying the code. (But if you're going to do that, you could also simply copy the function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a global variable like this:

```
function ($) {
    // there is codes here
    function _disable(input, v) { // I need this function 
        _o(input).prop('disabled', v);
        input.prop('disabled', v);
        var input_div = _getInputpickerDiv(input);
        if (v) {
            input_div.find('.inputpicker-arrow').hide();
        }
        else {
            input_div.find('.inputpicker-arrow').show();
        }
    }
    // there is codes here
    // make it available outside the scope
    window._disable = _disable
});
```

And access it later like this:

```
_disable(...)
```